# How do I create a property of a user control to control the value of a storyboard keyframe?

Tags: silverlight, xaml, windows-phone-7

As an intro to User Controls, I'm trying to create an LED User Control. When adding the LEDControl to my xaml, I want to be able to specify the color of the LED, LEDColor.  I've added two storyboards to the LED, TurnOn, and TurnOff, that animate the Rectangle fill color between 'off' (grey) and 'on' (LEDColor).

**How do I dynamically specify the color that the the storyboard will use for the 'To' value?**

Note, I am using Silverlight for Windows Phone.  At this point, I'm targetting wp7 but open to Mango soltions if it makes it more sense.

Answer (score 1):

Very simply, you just set the value like you set any other with a storyboard.

Here I've used a `{StaticResource LEDColor}` for the colour. Just bear in mind, it needs to be a Brush, and not a Color.

It's modifying a `Rectagle` named `LEDControl` and have a `0.5` second animation time.

```
<Storyboard x:Name="TurnOn">
    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="LEDControl">
        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Grey"/>
    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="LEDControl">
        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0.5" Value="{StaticResource LEDColor}"/>
    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
</Storyboard>

<Storyboard x:Name="TurnOff">
    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="LEDControl">
        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource LEDColor}"/>
    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="LEDControl">
        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0.5" Value="Grey"/>
    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
</Storyboard>
```

Comment: Ah this looks exactly what I'm looking for.  Hopefully, I'll try it tonight when I get home and update this thread.  Thanks for answering!

Comment: So I gave this a try but I was getting an error about not being able to find the LEDColor resource.  In the User Control code-behind, I have a property on the usercontrol class called LEDColor.  Do I need this?  What else do I need to do to hook these up?  Thanks for the help.

Comment: You need to understand how [resource dictionaries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.resourcedictionary.aspx) works for a start.

Answer (score 0):

You May have to be more precise when asking questions.

but if your talking about what i think you are, you should be able to change the state with the storyboard action so when that storyboard action is called it will also Change the fill color.

so when your recording the action for the StoryBoard, on the ON StoryBoard also change the color in the properties panel.

This is of course if your using Blend 4.